# Database connection - Django is auto renaming or something! CONFUSION

Tags: python, mysql, database, django

making blog thing, database, etc. Thing is, I have a database named 'posts'.

```
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
    'NAME': 'posts',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
    'USER': '*******',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
    'PASSWORD': '*******',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
    'HOST': '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
    'PORT': '****',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
}
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class posts(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    bodytext = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from models import posts 



#from settings import default
def index(request):
    entries = posts.objects.all()[:10]
    return render_to_response('homepage/index.html', {'posts' : entries}
```

output

```
OperationalError at /
(1049, "Unknown database 'posts.homepage_posts'")
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.4
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
(1049, "Unknown database 'posts.homepage_posts'")
Exception Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py in __init__, line 187
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.1
Python Path:    
['/Users/thor/Sites/FirstBlog',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 2 May 2012 19:56:53 -0500
```

It automatically suffixes `.homepage_posts` to the database name, making it impossible to access it. Please help?

Comment: Have you done a `./manage.py syncdb` and was it successful? The other thing to try is looking at the tables directly (`./manage.py dbshell` then `SHOW TABLES`) to see what is going on.

Comment: I do not think the problem is that it is accessing `posts.homepage_posts` -- that is a valid database.table_name format.  MySQL is just telling you that the posts part of that is invalid because the database does not exist.  So yes, make sure you've run `./manage.py syncdb`.

Answer (score 0):

The django default naming convention for how it auto-generates your tables is to prefix the table name with `<app_label>_`
You obviously have this mode/view inside of an app named "homepage". This is valid, and is not your issue. django does this to namespace your various tables between different apps and prevent name collisions when mixing in 3rd party apps.

This error is telling you that the entire database does not exist. It almost 100% means you have not told django to populate your database from your models structures:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

Run this now, and also every time you add new apps, or create new models. It will generate your database and your tables.

You can also control the actual name of the database tables if you really care, by setting the meta "db_table" field for your model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#db-table

```
class posts(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'foo_bar'
```

... But again, thats a separate issue altogether.